# Delete Site Collection on SharePoint 2013 (On-Prem) using CSOM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I want to delete Site collection with all sub-sites using CSOM on SharePoint 2013 On-Prem. I've tried with `web.DeleteObject()` but its works only for sub-sites not for top level site. Pls let me know if there is any other to achieve this way by using CSOM.

Comment: You can indeed delete Site Collections via csom. However, if the Site Collections have existing sub Sites, you may see an error.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot delete Site Collection using CSOM and you will have to rely on either PowerShell or Web Services. you can do it in on SharePoint-Online.

> The account that accesses this Web service must be a member of the
>   Farm Administrators group in the Central Administration site. By
>   default, the server's local Administrators group is in the Farm
>   Administrators group. To access the Admin service and its methods, set
>   a Web reference to http://Server_Name:Port_Number/_vti_adm/Admin.asmx.

Source: [Link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c1f2c2d9-430c-4688-a057-0492db5095c5/delete-site-collection-using-client-object-model)

Answer (score 0):

This works in SharePoint 2016

```
var ctx = new ClientContextWrapper(targetUrl);
var tenant = new Tenant(ctx);
var spoOperation = tenant.RemoveSite(targetUrl);
ctx.Load(spoOperation);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

If you're in 2013, you may need some extra PowerShell steps to configure your farm - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2014/06/09/provisioning-site-collections-using-sp-app-model-in-on-premises-with-just-csom/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665774/remove-site-collection-in-sharepoint-2013-using-csom#30242675